# Add annotation while changing method signature in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations, refactoring, method-signature

I want to change the method signature in eclipse via refactoring. Is it possible to add a new parameter with annotation which refactoring?
i.e.:
I have a method:

```
public void foo(int a) ;
```

Now I want to refactor it like:

```
public void foo(int a, @Someannotation int b);
```

P.S. I am using **eclipse helios**.

**EDIT :** 
currently It supports following things:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible today. There is also a bug opened for this - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=381449

Answer (score 1):

Add the new parameter without the annotation. Eclipse will add the default value of the new argument to all the method *invocations*. Then add the annotation in the method *definition*: it's defined only once, and it shouldn't be too hard to type `@Someannotation` in the source editor.

Comment: But my requirements are like: I would refactor in interface and It should  refactor in all its implementor classes also.

Comment: Do you really have so many classes implementing this interface?

Comment: Scenario is I have 1 interface and 5 implementor classes. And I need to change around 15 methods total. Now it looks like hell big.

Comment: I was looking for an automated way rather manually doing that.